# How in query Eloquent specify condition with relations

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I have 2 tables:

### articles

### id | title | category_id | created_at | updated_at |

### and categories

### id | name | descriptions | created_at | updated_at |

Relations : category `hasMany-> articles` and articles `belongsTo -> category`.

how simple way make query something like :

```
public functions getArticles ($category) { 

   $articles = Articles::where('category', '=', $category);

}
```

In documentations exist example with Id (http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#one-to-many ) , but I want select articles, knowing name category.

How in query specify condition with relations ?

If exist such methods, please help me.
Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `whereHas` method. Like:

```
$articles = Articles::whereHas('category', function($query)use($category){
    $query->where('name', $category->name);
});
```

I suppose that should work. Or you can just create a `scope` and join `categories` table and then check by it.

Comment: Thanks ) It's working !
Can I ask you yet question ?
P.S. Спасибо ;)

Comment: I want to sort multiple columns.
Tell me, maybe you know, where I can read or see example of sorting in view ?
For example, articles sort by author or date of publish. 
like here http://www.speedtest.net/results.php

Comment: maybe this make with the help of jQuery ?

Comment: Just pass the order in your url like ```http://somepage.org/search?order[publish_date]=desc&order[id]=asc``` and then grab all the orders in your controller with ```Input::get('order', [])``` and iterate over them adding new orders to your query like 
```foreach($orders as $key=>$order){
    $query->orderBy($key, $order);
}```

Comment: Thank you ) If I'll have some questions, can I write here ?

Comment: Максим, подскажи пожалуйста если в курсе : у меня есть сайт на Wordpress (например domain.com)  я хочу установить Laravel, чтоб приложение на нём было доступно по адресу domain.com/my_app. с устанавливаю Laravel в нужную папку и страница приветствия мне доступна по адресу domain.com/my_app/public, я хочу убрать сегмент public  из урла, редактирую .htaccess и всё равно ничего не получается. перечитал тут кучу постов и всё равно ничё не понял. помоги пожалуйста.